# Set Material Persistent Bottom Sheet height to half of the screen height?

Tags: java, android, material-design

So i have created a persistent bottom sheet inside a Coordinator Layout. I can set the height of `LinearLayout` to some value `500dp` But what i want to acheive is set it's height to half of the screen. I think i have to get the screen height through `DisplayMetrics` and somehow apply it on `LinearLayout`

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".post.PostActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gallery_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_very_small"
        android:background="@drawable/background_sheet"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/peek_height"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/width_forty"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_large"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:background="?android:listDivider" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gallery_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/grid_spacing"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_spacing" />

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculated the required screen height through `DisplayMetrics`

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

int halfScreenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2;
```

Then get the `getLayoutParams()` of the existing `linearLayout`. Set the height and applied. (Casted it to `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` as well)

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.gallery_bottom_sheet);

CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout.getLayoutParams();

params.height = halfScreenHeight;

linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int requiredHeight = height/2;
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.gallery_bottom_sheet);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, requiredHeight);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Just copy paste the above code inside your java file.

Comment: This throws an exception already replied in the comment ```java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams```

Comment: Try this:
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, requiredHeight);

Comment: What's the difference between this and above?

Comment: You are using an older version of Android Studio most probably.

Comment: ```Android Studio 3.6.3
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135, built on April 14, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 2014M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.google.services.firebase```

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.gallery_bottom_sheet);
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = (int) displayMetrics.heightPixels/2;
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Just copy paste the above code to your java file, inside "onCreate" method.